# how to select a particular set of rows in a table in the program without the user needing to select them using the mouse?

Tags: swing

I am using JTable. Suppose I have a table which contains the following information -

```
    **col1     col2    col3    col4**
```

**row1**    ---      value1   ---    ---
**row2**    ---      value2   ---    ---
**row3**    ---      value3   ---    ---
**row4**    ---      value3   ---    ---
**row5**    ---      value1   ---    ---
**row6**    ---      value1   ---    ---
**row7**    ---      value2   ---    ---
**row8**    ---      value1   ---    ---

I need to copy the rows which have the value of col2 as "value1" into another table.

For selecting the rows by hand (mouse click) there is a function called - getSelectedRows() where the work will be over in seconds i.e.

int [] rows = inputTable.getSelectedRows();     // "rows" is getting the array of indexes                     of the rows in the table

but now I need to do the same thing without mouse selection. i.e. int [] rows should get the rows indexes without using the above method but I can use any other methods without mouse selection that is...

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> searchedRows = new ArrayList<String>(); 
for (int rowIndex=0; rowIndex < rowCount; rowIndex++) {
  String value = (String)table.getValueAt(rowIndex,varColNumber); 
  if ("value1".equals(value)) {
    searchedRows.add(rowIndex);
  } 
 } 
 // here in the List searchedRows you have the rows numbers where the column is equals to the string "value1".
```

Hope it helps..

Comment: Do they return the indexes of the rows? They all seem to be void methods to me...and i am not supposed to use any listener interface as I am hardcoding this (i.e. selecting the rows which have value1 and then copying them into another table)

Comment: I believed you want to force selection on table. Sorry. I'm not sure to understand what you want. You want the indexes of the row where col2="value1" ? Nothing to do with selection of rows ? You can loop and collect row where value1.equals.getValue(row,col) Not fantastic...

Comment: I'm sorry to have confused you.                                     I would like to do something this way-                                  int varColNumber = findColumn(inputTable, "col2");
   int rowCount = inputTable.getRowCount();
   for(int k=0; k<rowCount; k++)
   {
// String [] values = (String) inputTable.getValueAt( ?  , varColNumber);
   }

Comment: for (int rowIndex=0; rowIndex < rowCount; rowIndex++) { String value = (String)table.getValueAt(rowIndex,varColNumber); }

Comment: I need to get all the values in a particular column. That is the reason I've used String [] values. I would be doing a comparison with the array values and then select the rows to copy into another table.

Comment: String[] values = new String[rowCount]; for (int rowIndex=0; rowIndex < rowCount; rowIndex++) { values[rowIndex] = (String)table.getValueAt(rowIndex,varColNumber); } // here you have all values of varColNumber in values

Comment: You could also do that : List<String> searchedRows = new ArrayList<String>(); for (int rowIndex=0; rowIndex < rowCount; rowIndex++) { String value  = (String)table.getValueAt(rowIndex,varColNumber); if ("value1".equals(value1)) { searchedRows.add(rowIndex);} } // here in the List searchedRows you have the rows numbers where the column is equals to the string "value1". Hope it helps...

Comment: I have edited the answer, may be you could mark it as useful and close the question ?